# SeleniumでIE Driverを使用し、edge IEモードにてScreen Lock画面中に操作したい

Tags: c#, selenium

EdgeをIEモードで立ち上げ、IE Driverを用いてサイトを開き、操作しています。
通常使用するのであれば問題無いのですが、スクリーンをロックした状態で使用したいと考えています。

しかし、画像の様にスクリーンをロックした状態ですと指定したサイトを開くことができません。
回避方法をご存知でしたらご教示ください。

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int retryCount = 0; retryCount <= 2; retryCount++)
        try
        {
            var options = new InternetExplorerOptions
            {
                IgnoreZoomLevel = true,
                AttachToEdgeChrome = true,
                EdgeExecutablePath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe")
            };
            using (var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(options))
            {
                try {
                    //Yahoo!を開く
                    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.yahoo.co.jp/");
                }
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: `headless`モードが使えるか試してみてはどうでしょう？ [Edge固有の機能](https://www.selenium.dev/ja/documentation/webdriver/browsers/edge/), [IE specific functionality](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browsers/internet_explorer/)